# Least Common Multiple of 3 modulo equations

Tags: elementary-number-theory

```
i%7=1   ->  i=1+7n
i%9=2   ->  i=2+9n
i%11=3  ->  i=3+11n
```

Besides writing out everything:

```
1,8,15,22...
2,11,20,29...
3,14,25,36...
```

to find the LCM. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: [Chinese remainder theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, you should use the [Chinese Remainder Theorem.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem)

However, for these **particular** numbers, there is a trick! Note that the congruences are equivalent to $2x+5\equiv 0\pmod{7}$, $2x+5\equiv 0\pmod{9}$, and $2x+5\equiv 0\pmod{11}$.  So we want $2x+5$ to be divisible by $7$, $9$, and $11$, and therefore by $(7)(9)(11)$, which is $693$. So $2x+5=693$ will work. That gives $x=344$.

**Remark:** If you are not familiar with congruence notation, look at the sequences of numbers you produced. We will concentrate on the first one, which was $1,8,15,22,\dots$ (there was a mild typo).

**Double** these, and **add** $5$. We get $7,21, 35, 49,\dots$, the odd multiples of $7$. Similarly, when you double the numbers in your second sequence, and add $5$, you get the odd multiples of $9$. Similar treatment to the third sequence gets you the odd multiples of $11$. So we want $2x+5$ to be an odd multiple of $(7)(9)(11)$. The smallest positive one is $693$. So now solve $2x+5=693$.

You can also carry through the same argument using the language of remainders. We want $(2x+5)\%7=0$, $(2x+5)\%9=0$, and $(2x+5)\%11=0$.

Comment: I thought OP wanted the least number that satisfied all three relations, which was why I suggested CRT. I agree that it is quite unclear.

Comment: @MJD: You are almost certainly right. The question needs to be reworded a bit.

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{eqnarray}\rm {\bf Hint} &&\rm\qquad\ x &\equiv&\rm n\pmod{2n\!+\!5},\ \ n = 1,2,3\\
\Rightarrow &&\rm\ 2x\!+\!5 &\equiv&\rm 0\pmod{2n\!+\!5},\ \ n = 1,2,3 \end{eqnarray}$

Thus $\rm\:7,9,11\: |\: 2x\!+\!5\:\Rightarrow\: lcm(7,9,11) = 693\:|\:2x\!+\!5.\:$

Therefore $\rm\ mod\ 693\!:\,\ x \,\equiv\, \dfrac{-5}2\,\equiv\, \dfrac{693-5}2 \,\equiv\, 344.$

**Remark** $ $ The idea generalizes: see [CCRT for congruences in A.P.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3281011/242) (Arithmetic Progression).