# Smallest integer which leaves remainder 3, 2, 1 when divided by 17, 15, 13

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem

Find the smallest positive integer so that the remainder when it is divided by $17,15,13$ is $3,2,1$ respectively.

This question can be solved using Chinese remainder theorem, but the theorem gives any integer, not the smallest.

For example, we have, letting $n_1, n_2, n_3 = 17, 15, 13$ and $a_1, a_2, a_3 = 3, 2, 1$ and $N_j = \frac{1}{n_j}\cdot\prod n_i$:

$$x = \sum a_i N_i^{\phi(n_i)}
\\x = 3\cdot(15\cdot 13)^{16} + 2\cdot(17\cdot13)^{8} + (17\cdot 15)^{12}$$

Essentially here $ N_1^{15} = (15\cdot 13)^{15}$ is root of $N_1 x \equiv 1(\mathrm{mod} \ 17)$

By choosing different roots, we get different answers, but how can we find the minimum $x$ that satisfies the condition?

Just so in this case the minimum is $1652$

Comment: "This question can be solved using Chinese remainder theorem, but the theorem gives any integer, not the smallest. "  But it gives you set of solution $k \pmod {15*17*13}$.  To find the smallest positive just find the one $n$ so that $0 \le n < 15*17*13$ and $n \equiv k \pmod{15*17*13}$.  The CRT will give you *precisely* that.

Comment: "By choosing different roots, we get different answers, but how can we find the minimum x that satisfies the condition?"  All the answers (if you did this correctly) will be $\equiv k \pmod{13*15*17}$ just add or subtract $13*15*17$ until you get the one representation that is between $0$ and $13*15*17$.  There will be exactly one such number.

Comment: @fleablood CRT is huge overkill since it boils down to simply computing the modular fraction $\, -11/2\bmod n  = (n-11)/2\,$ for any odd $\,n,\,$ see my answer.

Comment: @BillDubuque  No argument here.  I almost never use CRT to actually *find* the solutions but to allow me to state there is exactly one $\pmod{13*15*17}$.  My point is that if we can find *ANY* solution $n_1$, we can find the least positive be finding $n \equiv n_1 \pmod{13*15*17}$ and $0 \le n < 13*15*17$.  Which is exceedingly easy.  That seemed to be the OP's question: CRT (or any) method gives me many answers; how to I find the least positive.  Well... add or subtract $13*15*17$ until you get the one value between $0$ and $13*15*17$.

Comment: @fleablood Yes, agreed. I try (perhaps too hard) to nudge others to learn these useful methods so they can help pass on the torch from our forefathers. Some of these methods are rarely discussed in textbooks / lectures and deserve to be much better known. Alas, nowadays I don't have so much time so my answers are often so late that it seems nobody reads them. We need a better platform.

Comment: Well... that's math being as much an art as a science.  To get the art you have to have an aha moment.  If you try to teach it and the overwhelmed students attempt to learn it by rote which is exactly *not* the spirit it was taught in it just turns into extra noise that does more harm than good.  But if you rely on "do this; it will always work" than it's just way too much work.  And actually, I didn't even *try* to solve this question. I just wanted to address the unique modulo solution $\iff$ smallest positive solution is actually a non-issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system is 
$$\begin{cases}
x\equiv 3 \pmod{17} \\
x\equiv 2 \pmod{15} \\
x\equiv 1 \pmod{13}
\end{cases}$$
and it's solution is given by $x\equiv 1652 \pmod{3315}$, which means 
$$x=1652+3315t$$
for some $t\in \mathbb{Z}$. Making $t=0$ gives you the smallest positive integer (in this case, the remainder).

Comment: Oops I am stupid as hell, 3315 must be lcm

Answer (score 3):

CRT becomes trivial via the innate **Arithmetic Progression** (A.P.) structure. Note

$$\begin{align} &x\equiv 1\!\!\pmod{\!13}\\ &x\equiv 2\!\!\pmod{\!15}\\ &x\equiv 3\!\!\pmod{\!17}\\[.2em] {\rm i.e.}\ \ \ &x\equiv 1\!+\!k\!\!\!\pmod{\!13\!+\!2k},\ \ k=0,1,2\end{align}$$

with **progressions:** $\ 1,2,3 = 1\!+\!k,\ $ & $\,\ 13,15,17 = 13\!+\!2k.\,$ Hence

$\!\!\bmod \color{#c00}{13\!+\!2k}\!:\,\   x\equiv 1\!+\!k\overset{\small (2,13+2k)=1}\iff 2x \equiv 2\!+\!\color{#c00}{2k}\equiv 2\color{#c00}{-13}\equiv -11\iff 2x\!+\!11\equiv 0$

So $\ 13,15,17\mid 2x\!+\!11 \!\iff\! n\!=\!13(15)17\mid 2x\!+\!11,\,$ by [lcm = product for pair-coprimes.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1982395/242)

So $\bmod n\!:\,\  2x \equiv -11\equiv n\!-\!11\iff x \equiv (n\!-\!11)/2\equiv \bbox[5px,border:1px solid #c00]{\!\!1652}\:$ by $\,n=3315\,$ is odd.

Hence $\ x = 1652 + 3315\,k,\, $ so $\,x = 1652\,$ is clearly the smallest positive solution.

**Remark** $\ $ If modular fractions are known then more clearly we have by [CCRT](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/190522/242)

$$ x\equiv \dfrac{-11}2\!\!\! \pmod{\!13,15,17} \iff x\equiv \dfrac{-11}2\!\!\! \pmod {\!13\cdot 15\cdot 17}\qquad\qquad$$

More generally the same method shows that  if $\,(a,b) = 1\,$ then

$\bbox[8px,border:1px solid #c00]{{\bf Theorem} \ \ \left\{\:\!x\equiv d\!+\!ck\pmod{\!b\!+\!ak}\:\!\right\}_{k=0}^{m_{\phantom{|}}}\!\!\iff\! x\equiv \dfrac{ad\!-\!bc}a\pmod{\!{\rm lcm}\{b\!+\!ak\}_{k=0}^{m_{\phantom{|}}}}} $

**Proof** $ $ by $\,(a,b\!+\!ak)=(a,b)=1,\,$ LHS $\!\overset{\times\ a}\iff\!\bmod \color{#c00}{b\!+\!ak}\!:\ ax\equiv ad\!+\!c(\color{#c00}{ak})\equiv ad\!\color{#c00}{-b}c\!$  $\!\iff\! ax\!-\!(ad\!-\!bc)\,$ is divisible by all moduli $\!\iff\!$ it is divisible by their lcm $n\, $ (since $\,a\,$ is coprime to each modulus $\,n_k\,$ it is invertible $\!\bmod n_k\,$ so it is invertible mod their lcm $ n)$.

OP is special case $\ a,b,c,d = 2,13,1,1\,$  so $\ x\equiv \dfrac{2(1)\!-\!13(1)}2\equiv\dfrac{-11}2\!\pmod{\!17(16)13}$

See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3912487/242) for how to choose the residues in A.P. when only the moduli are in A.P.

Comment: At first I thought you were using complex numbers ($i^2=-1$), but now I realized it's very straightforward; I can see right away that it's $-2x\equiv11\mod 17,15,13\implies2x\equiv3304\mod 3315\implies x\equiv1652\mod 3315$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Thanks, it's no longer *imaginary* (but will quaternion aficionados similarly object to $\,k)?\,$ I didn't jump straight to $\,2x\equiv -11\,$ since I want to show how to *derive* it, vs. pull it out of a hat like magic.

Answer (score 1):

If $x\equiv3\mod 17$ and $x\equiv2\mod 15,$ then $17a+3\equiv 15b+2\mod 17\times15,$

so $17a+3\equiv2\mod 15,$ so $17a\equiv -1 \mod 15,$ so $2a\equiv -1\mod 15,$ so $a\equiv7 \mod 15,$

so $x=17(15c+7)+3=255c+122$.

If also $x\equiv1\mod 13$ then $255c+122\equiv13e+1$ so $255c+122\equiv1 \mod 13,$

so $255c\equiv-121\mod 13,$ so $8c\equiv9 \mod 13,$ so $c\equiv45\equiv6\mod 13,$ so $c=13d+6,$

so $x=255c+122=255(13d+6)+122=3315d+1652.$

Comment: Nice elementary way without using crt

Comment: @jeea Actually there is an *extremely easy way* without CRT - see my answer.