# What is the 3 digits number which when divided by 7, 8 and 9 leaves a remainder of 1, 4 and 7 respectively?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

I tried to write it as $$\overline{abc}=7k+1$$ $$\overline{abc}=8p+4$$ $$\overline{abc}=9t+7$$ but I have no idea what to next since I can't add or substract any value to find the least common multiple.

Another approach I have tried was to rewrite those relations as $$\overline{abc}=7(k+1)-6$$ $$\overline{abc}=8(p+1)-4$$ $$\overline{abc}=9(t+1)-2$$

I can see that $\overline{abc}$ must be an even number divisible by $4$ so $c\in{0,2,4,6,8}$ but here I got stuck.

Comment: Hint : You need the chinese remainder theorem

Comment: There are two $3$ digit-numbers with this property.

Comment: As @Peter mentioned, the Chinese remainder theorem is the best option. Are you familiar with it so we can use it in the answer? Could you provide the source of the problem (a course, homework, exercise, a puzzle by a friend, a random question in your mind) and if you've learnt any theorems or methods in number theory before?

Comment: This was a subject from an olympiad. I didn't know about Chinese remainder theorem, but I don't mind to learn it, quite the contrary, I'll study.

Comment: Do you know basic operations in modular arithmetic? Then I may be able to post an answer that will be coherent to you.

Comment: The exercise is formulated as if the number would be unique. If it was actually formulated exactly this way , it is a bad exercise for olympia-level.

Comment: @DS, yes, I know, I would really appreciate

Comment: then here you go

Comment: As [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3281011/242) in the linked dupe, it can be **solved in $10$ seconds of minute of mental arithmetic** as follows:
$\!\!\underbrace{\bmod 7\!+\!k}_{\textstyle \color{#c00}{k\equiv -7}}\!:\ x \equiv 1\!+\!3\color{#c00}k \equiv 1\!+\!3(\color{#c00}{-7})\equiv -20,\,$ so $\,x\equiv -20\equiv 484\pmod{\!7\!\cdot\! 8\!\cdot\! 9}\,$ by [CCRT or lcm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2006919/242) $\ \ $

Comment: Alternative to the above CRT arithmetic progression optimization: we can instead (mechanically) apply [(Easy) CRT](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/20259/242) to solve it by repeatedly replacing a pair of congruences by a single equivalence congruence, as explained in the prior linked post. $\ \ $

Answer (score 2):

Let your number be $x$. We have:
$$x \equiv 1 \mod 7 \tag{1}\label{1}$$
$$x\equiv 4 \mod 8\tag{2}\label{2}$$
$$x \equiv 7 \mod 9\tag{3}\label{3}$$
Let's rewrite the last equivalence:
$$x = 9p+7\tag{4}\label{4}$$for some integer $p$. Put $\eqref{4}$ in $\eqref{2}$:
$$9p+7 \equiv 4 \mod 8$$
$$p \equiv 5 \mod 8$$
Rewriting:
$$p = 8q+5\tag{5}\label{5}$$
for some integer q. Put $\eqref{5}$ in $\eqref{4}$:
$$x=9(8q+5)+7$$
$$x=72q+45+7$$
$$x = 72q+52\tag{6}\label{6}$$
Put $\eqref{6}$ in $\eqref{1}$:
$$72q+52\equiv 1 \mod 7$$
$$2q+3 \equiv 1 \mod 7$$
$$2q \equiv 5 \mod 7$$
$$2q \equiv 12 \mod 7$$
$$q \equiv 6 \mod 7$$
Rewriting:
$$q = 7k+6\tag{7}\label{7}$$
for some integer $k$. Put $\eqref{7}$ in $\eqref{6}$:
$$x = 72(7k+6) + 52$$
$$\color{green}{x = 504k+484}$$It is trivial from here. There are $2$ such numbers.
As an exercise, try to see why this general form of $x$ would satisfy the conditions.

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: @downvoter please mention if the post can be improved in any way

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: @BillDubuque I had no idea this was a duplicate. I answered long before it was closed

Comment: also, the questions cited for closing this question do not answer the exact same question...

Comment: The site is over $13$ years old so of course we already have *hundreds* of answers explaining how to apply CRT as you do above. There is nothing novel above. This can be solved in $10$ seconds - see my comment on the question.

Comment: well I didn't know we consider similar questions as duplicates

Comment: See [abstract duplicates](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1756/242). Now you know.

Comment: @BillDubuque thanks for the guidance! Is there a way to find out if there are duplicates (or abstract duplicates) to a question apart from scanning the **Related** on the right side?

Comment: There are many posts on meta on site searching, e.g. [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265/242).